# Calling Virtual Function in FormCreate

Tags: delphi

I am playing with an already existing code. I have a base class form where i introduce a virtual function and calling the function in FormCreate. In some derived class i override the function and have my own implementation. But when i am executing the application i am  getting "EAbstract error". I dont know why i am getting this exception. When i debugged it is FormCreate is executing well for some forms but for some other forms i am getting this exception. I am new to Delphi so ignore my ignorance. Thanks.

Comment: You must miss to override that abstract method since the `EAbstractError` is raised when you call an abstract method.

Comment: or you have used `inherited myFunction` where you shouldn't (ie you call the ahchestor's abstract method).

Comment: @TLama: No it is not an abstract method, it is just a virtual function

Comment: Any attempts to create an abstract class within the function or the overrides?

Comment: @Jeeva, if it were just virtual, you wouldn't get `EAbstractError` even if that virtual method were empty, or even if you would call `inherited` in the abstract method class's descendant. bummi's note might be the reason.

Comment: @Jeeva Show the sources then, declaration and implementation of those method and FormCreate and whatever relevant to code flow in your case. Also edit tags and add delphi version to tags please

Comment: Perhaps the code in your virtual function does cause the problem (e.g. TStrings.Create)

Comment: I could think of a problematic implementation like this:  function TTemplate.GetGraphicClass: TGraphicClass;// implemented virtual
begin
  Result := TGraphic;
end;

procedure TTemplate.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
 Graphic:TGraphic;
begin
    Graphic :=GetGraphicClass.Create;
    // some additional code
    Canvas.Draw(0,0,Graphic);
end;

Comment: Are you using form inheritance?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your program is a class which declares an abstract virtual:

```
procedure Foo; virtual; abstract;
```

And your program instantiates a class that does not override this abstract method, and then calls the method. When this method is called, an EAbstractError exception is raised.

The abstract method is not necessarily declared in code that you wrote. For example, perhaps you instantiated a TStrings class:

```
Strings := TStrings.Create;
```

when you meant to write

```
Strings := TStringList.Create;
```

Subsequent method calls on the TStrings instance will lead to abstract errors. Remember that TStrings is an abstract class full of abstract methods.

With many patterns of class instantiation your code would lead to a compiler warning. The compiler will warn that you are instantiating a class that contains abstract methods. If your mistake is as suggested above, then the compiler warnings will locate the error for you. I cannot stress enough the importance of listening to the compiler's warnings.

However, if the abstract class in question is a form, then the compiler will not be able to warn if you are using Application.CreateForm to instantiate it.

If your code declares the abstract method, then you can find the problem readily by performing a search (Find in Files) for the uses of abstract. If that does not help, and there are no compiler warnings, then configure the debugger to break on exceptions and then take a look at the call stack when the program breaks on the exception.

Comment: This class works fine until i introduce this virtual function and i haven't used abstract. If i remove this function and its overrides my application works fine. Since it is a very big code base i am finding hard to determine the root cause.

Comment: I've described what leads to EAbstractError. Clearly you are calling an abstract method.

Comment: Use the debugger then. If you cannot work it out with the debugger, create a small but complete program that illustrates the issue.

Comment: Oh it is a complete mess up. I restarted my system and everything worked just fine

Comment: Well, clearly the code changed. But the version that failed, the reasons are as described above.